# Scriptural verses that assign masculinity and femininity to varnas

Tags: puranas, brahmins, varna, kshatriya, gender

So my friend (of the Katyayan gotra) she is saying that kshatriyas are the masculine dominated varna, while braahmins are the androgynous dominated varna, a combination of masculine and feminine characteristics. Does this idea have any support in scripture?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an avid researcher just a curious fool but as far as i know(it's a lie i did a lot of research for the same) here is a part from Rigveda and i hope it will be able to answer your question.

> यत् पुरुषं व्यदधुः कतिधा व्यकल्पयन्। मुखं किम् अस्य कौ बाहू का ऊरू
> पादा उच्येते॥११॥ ब्राह्मणो ऽस्य मुखम् आसीद् बाहू राजन्यः कृतः। ऊरू तद्
> अस्य यद् वैश्यः पद्भ्यां शूद्रो अजायत॥१२॥
> 11 When they divided Puruṣa(divison of varna)
> how many portions did they make? What do they call his mouth, his
> arms? What do they call his thighs and feet? 12 The Brahmin was his
> mouth, of both his arms was the Rājanya made. His thighs became the
> Vaiśya, from his feet the Śūdra was produced.
> --Rigveda 10.90.11-2

As for the idea being related to scriptures i don't really want to state my opinion at least not until i can find an old scripture without any tempering or modification.

Comment: Is Katyayana gothra mean a Buddhist person?